# Let ios Distribution Certificate expire if I don't want new updates

Tags: ios, certificate, app-update, renewal

I got the email from Apple: "Your iOS Distribution Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To generate a new certificate, sign in and visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles."

It is already in the app store and I am not planning to put any updates out there in the future, I just want to leave the app the way it is in the app store. Is it then still necessary to renew the distribution certificates, or can I just ignore it? My app is using push notifications (in case this matters).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are on Enterprise or Standard iOS Developer program:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6

Short story is that for Standard program it's safe to do anything with your certs - all applications are resigned with Apple certificates in that case. So it's all good even if your certs will expire or if you revoke them manually.

For Enterprise it's a different story - but it's less likely to be your case.

Comment: I'm indeed on Standard Developer Program (Organization). Thanks for you response!